# Intellij-IDEA can start and debug jersey apps in tomcat, but deploy the war to tomcat got 404

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, web-applications, jersey

I have a jersey web-app, use IntelliJ IDEA as IDE. I use maven (pom.xml) as the project manager tools ---- use for dependency lib manager.

I use this debug configuration:

Server -> Application Server: Tomcat 9.0.24
URL : http://localhost:8080/

Deployment -> :war exploded
Application Context: /

then when I press the debug button, the project compile, and the artifact deployed, the browser open for welcome page (this is static page).

I use postman send GET or POST or PUT request, the correct response given.

when I Build/Artifacts..., IntelliJ IDEA created .war file.

I put the war file to remote Tomcat container webapps folder ---- all same as localhost ---- use ROOT.war name.

tomcat catalina.out file has this message:

> 20-Aug-2019 11:41:06.528 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>   20-Aug-2019 11:41:06.546 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>   20-Aug-2019 11:41:06.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [393] milliseconds
>   20-Aug-2019 11:41:06.587 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
>   20-Aug-2019 11:41:06.587 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
>   20-Aug-2019 11:41:06.603 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/root/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/webapps/ROOT.war]
>   20-Aug-2019 11:41:08.434 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>   20-Aug-2019 11:41:08.469 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/root/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/webapps/ROOT.war] has finished in [1,867] ms

I use postman send same request, get 404 error. use postman access static page, It's ok.

I google some matter, but not suit my scene. Here not tomcat Application context correct, not war file incorrect.

My project is not web.xml file. but I append web.xml, not luck.

I append tomcat7-maven-plugin to pom.xml file. not effect.

append org.glassfish.jersey.bundles jaxrs-ri lib to pom.xml. same.

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {
```

I use this Application of JAX-RS. 
so I access http://host-name:8080/api/..., tomcat give me not found.

I lookup the tomcat access log(localhost_access_log.2019-MM-DD.txt), give me this message:

> 114.249.235.124 - - [20/Aug/2019:11:53:12 +0800] "GET /api/subjects HTTP/1.1" 404 1047

why IntelliJ IDEA startup tomcat and deploy the project is ok, I use IntelliJ IDEA build the war file and put it to tomcat webapps/ROOT.war not work?

may the problem at where?

Comment: I put the war to localhost tomcat, It's ok.

Comment: localhost tomcat and remotehost tomcat is download from a url.

don't change anything of configure, only uncompress.

localhost os is macos 10.14.6, remotehost os is ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is solved. Caused by different Java versions. The Java on my machine is a high version, but the Java version on the Server is relatively low